# Cursor Update Python Script for Multiplying Several Fields against a Ratio (Real) in ArcGis

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcpy, field-calculator, fields-attributes

[image]Disclaimer: Python Neophyte, Uber-reliant on GUI, working to wean...

I have a Python script for replacing multiple Field values with another table value that was graciously provided by the inimitable DKlassen and seen here:

```
import arcpy
tablename = "c:\temp\*NAMEOFYOURTABLE*"
fieldvalues = ['fieldname1','fieldname2','fieldname3'......'fieldnameX']

cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor(tablename)
for row in cur:
    sourcevalue = row.getValue('*name of field where source value coming from*')
    for f in fieldvalues:
        row.setValue(f, sourcevalue)
    cur.updateRow(row)
```

Question: After running it it seems to replace all the fieldvalues with f and defaults integers to 0 or 1 (since sourcevalues is a real number between 0-1)--how do I include an operator to multiple for f in fieldvalues by a ratio, or real/float number? Obviously the syntax of f*sourcevalue does not work.

Comment: Are you able to reduce your example code (which looks fine) to just one hardwired field in place of '*name of field where source value coming from*' and one field instead of your list of fields and see if you get the expected result because f*sourcevalue can produce floats so it is may be a field definition preventing that going in.  To show f*sourcevalue can produce floats try "f = 2
sourcevalue = 1.1
print f*sourcevalue"

Comment: float(f) * float(sourcevalue) will force the result to be a float value.  Can you show us a few rows/columns in your table so we can get an better idea of what you are looking for. (or a screenshot).

Comment: Dklassen: Column A=Column_A* a float number--updating the current field. Poly Geo: what would the syntax be to run that test, where would I insert that snippet? EDIT Figured out screenshot, put it up top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grant Malcolm,
If you want to calculate - say Column B01001e1 with the PROPORTION field you would do the following:

```
cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor("block_senatedist13NAD83ft")
for row in cur:
    row.setValue("B01001e1", row.getValue("B01001e1") * row.getValue("PROPORTION"))
    cur.updateRow(row)
```

If you want to update multiple fields:

```
cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor("block_senatedist13NAD83ft")
fieldvalues = ["B01001e1","B01001e2"]
for row in cur:
    for f in fieldvalues:
        row.setValue(f, row.getValue(f) * row.getValue("PROPORTION"))
    cur.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Perfect. You're the best dklassen.

Comment: If you have any other ARCPY questions let me know.